# Internet Explorer - Javascript submit error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have forms with submit buttons that use javascript. The code looks following:

```
<form action="settings.php" method="post" id="myform" class="forms">
...some form fields here
<button type="submit" name="submit_ok" value="Save" onClick="document.myform.submit();">Save</button>
```

However, IE 10 (Win7 x64) displays this error when trying to submit form:

"Unable to get property submit of undefined or null reference"

All other browsers don't display any errors. If I click Yes when IE asks if I want to continue running scripts on this page, everything works well, but I need to remove this error badly.

Comment: It is a submit button, why in the world are you triggering submit when the button does it by default? remove the onclick, the form will do it.

Comment: Also, there is rarely a need to give a submit button a name—it's very tempting to call it "submit"… :-(

Comment: epascarello, like I said, there are more onClick events with other buttons (that do different things instead of submitting forms), so I asked in order to apply this solution to other buttons as well.

Comment: @RobG the primary reason to name submit buttons is when you have multiple. How else would you know (server-side) which one was pressed?

Comment: @Phil—of course, but that doesn't seem to be a common requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All form controls (such as buttons, inputs, etc) have a property `form` that references the parent `<form>` element. You can therefore use

   ```
   this.form.submit();
   ```
2. Why even bother doing it this way? Your submit button's default action will submit the form.
3. IE is probably looking for an element by name when traversing the `document` object. Your form has no `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Yes, I know the default action is to submit, but there are more onClick events with other buttons (that do different things instead of submitting forms), so I can apply this solution to other buttons as well.